# Can't call $.data on object inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, undefined

I'm playing around with the jQuery `$.data` function, and I'm running in to some trouble. If I do like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.testData = function() {
         var obj = $(this);
         obj.text($.data(obj,'test')); 
    }
})(jQuery);

var element = $("#test");
$.data(element,'test','hej');
element.testData();
```

this comes out as undefined. Why?

**EDIT:**

It works just fine if I use the `elem.data(key)` function, like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.testData = function() {
         var obj = $(this);
         obj.text(obj.data('test')); 
    }
})(jQuery);

var element = $("#test");
element.data('test','hej');
element.testData();
```

but I just saw an slideshow by Paul Irish, which claims that `elem.data` is 10x slower than `$.data(elem)`:
http://paulirish.com/2009/perf/

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding that presentation. He means that if you've *already got* a DOM element reference, then passing it directly to "$.data()" is faster than wrapping it in a jQuery object and using the ".data()" method. Since you're wrapping your object up ("$(this)") anyway, you're not getting the performance benefit at all.

Comment: Plus, calling `.data` to the selected object makes your code more clear (at least to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.testData = function() {
         var obj = $(this);
         obj.text($.data(obj[0],'test'));
    }

    var element = $("#test");
    $.data(element[0],'test','hej');
    element.testData();
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TdJHq/

Comment: this first argument of $.data function is the DOM element and not the jQuery object

Comment: @alexl: While this is true, it does not really explain the behaviour. E.g. this works perfectly: `var obj = $('#test'); $.data(obj,'test','hej'); alert($.data(obj,'test'));`.

Comment: True still try to figure it out now ... :)

Comment: Somehow when you pass data to the jquery object in the same context it works. But when you call a method here the testData one, the jquery object is copied into the $(this). At this point all the data are lost. So if you pass data to the dom object the data is saved into the two context. Maybe it's the answer but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating different objects for attaching and retrieving the data. Whenever you call `$(selector)`, you are creating a **new** jQuery object and this it will be different than the one you attached the data to.

Here is a simple example:

```
$.data($('#test'),'test','hej');
alert($.data($('#test'),'test'));
```

It will give you `undefined`.

That is why `$.data` expects a DOM element and not a jQuery object. No matter how you retrieve a certain DOM element, the reference is always the same.

So either pass the DOM element (`$('#test')[0]`) or **better**, use `$('#test').data()`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.data ([doc jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)) works on DOM elements, not on jQuery elements. So you must extract the real element under your jQuery selector.

```
obj.text($.data(obj[0],'test'));
```

This is what @alexl explained.

But there is also a [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method, that works on a jQuery selector, so you could use:

```
// getter
obj.text($obj.data('test'));
// setter
obj.text($obj.data('test','toto'));
```

And you may have mixed both.